# How to delete all html images using Notepad++ Expressions?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have about 150 images that are wrapped in links. I need to delete the images but not the links.

```
<a href="#whatever" title="my title"><img src="/img/floors/kellet/3.jpg" /></a>
```

What would be the expression for this using notepad++?

Comment: You select them (one by one) and you press 'delete'. (I was joking)

Comment: Have you also got images which are not wrapped in links and should not be deleted?

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex to capture all cases:

```
<img(?=\s|>)(?:(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+)?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this regex:

```
<img .*? />
```

It works with Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = '''<a href="#whatever" title="my title"><img src="/img/floors/kellet/3.jpg" /></a>'''
>>> re.sub(r'<img .*? />', '', string)
'<a href="#whatever" title="my title"></a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (will match images inside anchor tags only),

```
<a ?.*?><img ?.*? \/><\/a>
```

***p.s.** I am a beginner in regex.*